# Package does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, package, javac, jar

I get an "Build failed" error with error output when I try to build my project in Eclipse:

[javac] ......\src\example\servlet\ScrapingServlet.java:10: package org.apache.http.client does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

But the Eclipse editor does not give any error. I added the jars to the project with Project > properties > add external JARS... and all the JARS are showed in the project explorer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have to commons-httpclient on your classpath?

Comment: How can I check my classpath? I added all the JARS to the project with "add external JARS..." in Eclipse and I can see them in the project explorer.

Comment: Does you all JARS has commons-httpclient.jar in it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have just added the jars, sometimes you need to do a Clean and then build for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem. I had to add the filenames of the JARS to the build.xml file.

Comment: can you explain it in details?

Comment: Could you please explain in elaborate way? I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added `commons-httpclient.jar` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to added the jars to be copied in the build.xml, like this:

```
  <!-- copy JavaMail support jars build directory -->
<mkdir dir="${basedir}/jlib/javamail"/>  <!-- make sure 'from' dir exists to avoid warnings -->
<copy todir="${build.lib}" failonerror="false" verbose="false">
    <!-- ok if this file does not exist -->
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/jlib/javamail">
       <include name="activation.jar"/> <!-- not needed for JDK 6+ -->
       <include name="mail.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

this works for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error in **Android Studio**.

I was added a module dependency of a `libs/httpcomponents` directory I created that contained a number of `jar` files, including `commons-httpclient.jar` but that wasn't working for some reason.

Once I moved  `commons-httpclient.jar` to just the `libs/` directory and updated the module dependency by adding that file explicitly, the build worked fine.

Weird science.